# Consulta MySQL, Group by elimina filas

Tags: mysql, group-by

Tengo esta base de datos: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iEzOApVd3EKDd6caUc72s-bek1q0BaPd/view?usp=sharing

Y al correr este sql me salen solo 6 filas

```sql
SELECT 
  fac_week, 
  YEAR( fec_fac ) y
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      e.fec_fac, 
      WEEK(e.fec_fac, 1) fac_week, 
      0 sells, 
      0 exchange_sells, 
      SUM(de.can_pro * de.cos_pro) buys, 
      SUM(de.can_pro * de.cos_pro_bs) exchange_buys 
    FROM 
      entradas_salidas e 
      JOIN detalle_entradas_salidas de ON de.id_es = e.id 
    WHERE 
      e.id_movimiento = 1 
    GROUP BY 
      e.id 
    UNION 
    SELECT 
      f.fec_fac, 
      WEEK(f.fec_fac) fac_week, 
      SUM(d.pre_ven * d.can_ven) sells, 
      SUM(d.pre_ven * d.can_ven) * d.tasa_ven exchange_sells, 
      0 buys, 
      0 exchange_buys 
    FROM 
      facturas f 
      JOIN detalle_factura d ON d.id_factura = f.id 
    WHERE 
      f.tipo = 0 
    GROUP BY 
      f.id
  ) t
GROUP BY fac_week
HAVING 
  y = 2023  
ORDER BY `t`.`fac_week`  DESC;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando le quito el group by quedando asi

```sql
SELECT 
  fac_week, 
  YEAR( fec_fac ) y
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      e.fec_fac, 
      WEEK(e.fec_fac, 1) fac_week, 
      0 sells, 
      0 exchange_sells, 
      SUM(de.can_pro * de.cos_pro) buys, 
      SUM(de.can_pro * de.cos_pro_bs) exchange_buys 
    FROM 
      entradas_salidas e 
      JOIN detalle_entradas_salidas de ON de.id_es = e.id 
    WHERE 
      e.id_movimiento = 1 
    GROUP BY 
      e.id 
    UNION 
    SELECT 
      f.fec_fac, 
      WEEK(f.fec_fac) fac_week, 
      SUM(d.pre_ven * d.can_ven) sells, 
      SUM(d.pre_ven * d.can_ven) * d.tasa_ven exchange_sells, 
      0 buys, 
      0 exchange_buys 
    FROM 
      facturas f 
      JOIN detalle_factura d ON d.id_factura = f.id 
    WHERE 
      f.tipo = 0 
    GROUP BY 
      f.id
  ) t
HAVING 
  y = 2023  
ORDER BY `t`.`fac_week`  DESC;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me salen todos los resultados e incluso 'fac_week' que no estaban en el group by.
Pienso que en teoría el group by deberia de conservarme el resto de las filas que se muestran en la ultima foto, si se fijan 'fac_week' en la ultima foto, tiene filas de 36 y 35 pero cuando lo agrupo no.

Que creen que pueda estar pasando?

Comment: Pon la estructura de la tabla y datos de ejemplo en la pregunta misma: eso es crear un [repro]. El enlace que pasaste puede caer en cualquier momento, por lo tanto parte fundamental de la pregunta se perderá de ser así. Además, elimina la etiqueta _phpmyadmin_, ya que no tiene relación con la pregunta.

Comment: Bueno, para empezar, el GROUP BY te esta agrupando, valga la redundancia, por el id de entradas_salida y de facturas. Esto hace que no se muestre mas de una vez el mismo id. Otra cosa es que quizás el WHERE e.id_movimiento = 1 y WHERE f.tipo = 0 te esta excluyendo el resto de los registros al aplicar esa restricción. Podrías indicar la estructura de las tablas consultadas en tu Query?

Comment: Ya lo solvente, al final era que en el group by le tuve que poner la columna y

Comment: Ponlo entonces como respuesta, y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Y por cierto, no hagas caso omiso a los comentarios. Las preguntas y sus respuestas deben ser útiles _para todos_, no solo para un usuario en particular. Lee [ask] y [answer].

Comment: @padaleiana ok lo voy a leer gracias :)

Comment: @padaleiana y mala mia si no formule bien la pregunta sorry :/

Comment: @padaleiana tambien ya le quite la etiqueta phpmyadmin

Comment: No pidas perdón. Con modificar la pregunta para mostrar la estructura de las tablas, es suficiente.

Answer (score 0):

Solucion, funciona pero no se porque

```sql
SELECT 
  fac_week, 
  YEAR( fec_fac ) y
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      e.fec_fac, 
      WEEK(e.fec_fac, 1) fac_week, 
      0 sells, 
      0 exchange_sells, 
      SUM(de.can_pro * de.cos_pro) buys, 
      SUM(de.can_pro * de.cos_pro_bs) exchange_buys 
    FROM 
      entradas_salidas e 
      JOIN detalle_entradas_salidas de ON de.id_es = e.id 
    WHERE 
      e.id_movimiento = 1 
    GROUP BY 
      e.id 
    UNION 
    SELECT 
      f.fec_fac, 
      WEEK(f.fec_fac) fac_week, 
      SUM(d.pre_ven * d.can_ven) sells, 
      SUM(d.pre_ven * d.can_ven) * d.tasa_ven exchange_sells, 
      0 buys, 
      0 exchange_buys 
    FROM 
      facturas f 
      JOIN detalle_factura d ON d.id_factura = f.id 
    WHERE 
      f.tipo = 0 
    GROUP BY 
      f.id
  ) t
GROUP BY fac_week, y
HAVING 
  y = 2023  
ORDER BY `t`.`fac_week`  DESC;
```